# I would like to know if an object is in my Doctrine Collection

Tags: php, symfony1, doctrine

I'm working on Symfony 1.4 with Doctrine 1.2 and I have some problems.

I have created one Doctrine Collection of my Products like this :

```
$oProductCollection = new Doctrine_Collection('Products');
```

And I add some product in :

```
$oProductCollection->add($oMyProduct);
```

Then I want to know if a product is already in my Collection. Because if I add my product twice, that overwrite my old version...

I found "contains" function but I can't give my product object directly and I don't know what the key is...

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 6):

You can set the `keyColumn` by

```
//set the id column as key
$oProductCollection = new Doctrine_Collection('Products', 'id');
```

Then you can use `$oProductCollection->contains($oMyProduct->getId());` to check  whether `$oMyProduct` is already in your Collection.

Answer (score 2):

Now you are able to write

```
if ($oProductCollection->contains($oMyProduct)){
   echo "Its already in";
}else{
   $oProductCollection->add($oMyProduct);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative. Index your collection by id, and just check if it exists. It should be pretty fast. Take a look at the [docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm/1.2/docs/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language/zh#indexby-keyword).

Something like:

```
$id = $oMyProduct->getId();    
if (!empty($oProductCollection[$id])){
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should implement a method Produits::equals(Produit $p) check every object of the collection using a loop.

```
foreach ($oListeProduit as $p) {
  if ($p->equals($produit)) {
    return true;
  }
}
return false;
```

Comment: That's not very efficient, the xdazz method is better.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the second parameter of the `Doctrine_Collection` constructor:

```
public function __construct($table, $keyColumn = null)
```

So:

```
$oProductCollection = new Doctrine_Collection('Products', 'id');
```

And then `contains` with an id will work.

Edit: grilled :(

Comment: This solution is mine. Thanks